# Ecommerce database design and data selection

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I was not sure how to title this question, and I am having difficulty trying to describe the problem well. I have been struggling on how to setup my database for a site I am working on.

My problem is that I cant figure out how to properly setup items table. I have a company table which links to an items table which links to an itemSizePrice table. Since the system has multiple companies, which can all have multiple items, I cant figure out how to get at a specific itemID.

Database layout can be seen in this image: [image: Database]

Since each company can have multiple items, a select statement using companyID, for instance, would return many many lines. I thought about using something else that would be unique, such as the imagePath, since it is date and time stamped in the filename, but I need to get the ItemID in order to get the proper imagePath, to then get the itemID. Basically its a circle.

Is there a better way to setup this database? Can anyone help me out and give me an idea as to have to get at a single itemID?

Edit: I omitted the pieces of the database that are not relevant.

Comment: you itemId will be a unique primary key. You need to explain why that is a problem and what exactly you want to get from the schema.

Comment: The problem is how do I select an individual itemID. So say I want to update the imagepath. To do that I need to get the ItemID. How would I do this?

Comment: ItemID is unique identifier, so usually your application must know ID to do an Update. e.g. you show list of Items to the user in the list where ID is in the hidden field. When user makes an update you update a record using ItemId

Comment: I understand this. My problem is a simple statement such as: Select ItemId FROM Items where companyID = whatever; wont work because there will be multiple items with the same companyID. I need a way to select a specific itemID so that I can use it to Update something in that row.

Comment: But how do you know which item to Update? If your business logic says that each company can have many items, you cannot workaround it without. If it is 1-2-1 relation, than there will be no problem.

Comment: Hrmm. You know what. That question "But how do you know which item to Update?" Kind of made it click that im going about this wrong. I was trying to set it up where if I want to update the imagePath i can use the ItemID and itemName, or something. I think the reason im struggling with this is I am just doing it wrong. I think I am going to go ahead and try and figure out a different way where I can actually answer the question you posed to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the item information, you can able to get a single item based on item_id=x and company_id=y, but based on only company information you can't get a single item as the relationship between company and item is 1-2-many. so you must need the item information with company information.

If it's fine to get any one item among all the available for a company then you can use top 1 record or max(item_id), but i don't think this will be work out.